# conda dependencies install and management

Tags: anaconda, conda

I am struggling with versionning and dependencies with conda and python packages.

When doing : conda install -c conda-forge qt==5.6.2
it installs all the dependencies or None of them (-no-dependencies).

1) How to install/update selectively the dependencies ?
  (because some cause breakage for other packages).

2) I have a sandbox envs in conda where I test the install+regression test.
But, it works, I would like to reproduce the install in other environnment.
Is it a way to modify directly the config file of the environnement and add manually the new packages ?

For regression test, am also using 
https://github.com/pelson/conda-execute 
which allows temp envs setup with dependencies.

Comment: I would suggest you to use anaconda navigator. Because anaconda navigator provides you an option for installing packages for different environment example python 2.7 (A environment) / python 3.x (B environment). Please read this [How do I install Python packages in Anaconda?](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-install-Python-packages-in-Anaconda/answer/Jose-Praveen?srid=2dqQ)

Answer (score 0):

If it can help other people, stuck in this situation,
work around is using --force :

```
conda -c  channel install packagename --force
```

it will install only the package.
If you want to selectively install packages,
    conda -c channel packagename
and you can get the list of dependencies from where you can choose to install.